# Aeron active congestion control mode

Tags: c#, aeron

I encounter a problem when trying to activate the congestion control mode (the cubic one).
I use it in UDP *Multi-Destination-Cast* mode with the C driver as non embedded on the receiver side and embedded on the server side. I configure it like that:

```
var value = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("aeron_cubic_congestion_control_strategy_supplier");     
if (AeronDriverContextSetCongestioncontrolSupplier(_ctx, value) < 0)       
  throw new MediaDriverException($"AeronDriverContextSetCongestioncontrolSupplier: ({AeronErrcode()}) {AeronErrmsg()}");     

var supplier = AeronDriverContextGetCongestioncontrolSupplier(_ctx);         
    // Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(supplier) output "aeron_cubic_congestion_control_strategy_supplier"
```

Below the exception I get on the client side when trying to initiate the connection/subscription :

```
Adaptive.Agrona.Concurrent.AgentTerminationException: Exception of type 'Adaptive.Agrona.Concurrent.AgentTerminationException' was thrown.
   at Adaptive.Aeron.ClientConductor.DoWork()
   at Adaptive.Agrona.Concurrent.AgentRunner.DoDutyCycle(IIdleStrategy idleStrategy, IAgent agent)
```

I configure it only on the client side, am I correct ? My connection works well when I don't set this setting. Do I have to configure another setting in order to not have this *AgentTerminationException*  ? I am under Linux

Comment: isn't cubic a tcp congestion protocol?

Comment: yes true ; I guess Aeron implement an equivalent behavior which mimic the TCP cubic behavior @IłyaBursov

Comment: It seems we must use ```aeron_congestion_control_strategy_supplier_load("cubic")``` to get a pointer to the C function and pass it to ```aeron_driver_context_set_congestioncontrol_supplier```